# Closed form $\int_{0}^{\frac{r}{2}} {\binom{n}{p} \binom{n-p}{r-2p} 2^{r-2p}}{\binom{2n}{r}^{-1}} \ \text{d}p$

Tags: pr.probability, integration, binomial-coefficients

*Note:* This is exact copy of [my Math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3275005/find-int-0-fracr2-binomnp-binomn-pr-2p-2r-2p-binom2n), which [I am reposting here, as despite bounty it did not receive any answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30453/migrating-this-not-answered-bounty-expired-question-to-mathoverflow).

---

Let there be $n$ pairs of shoes in a box.
The the probability that from the $r \le n$ shoes I am taking out of the box there are exactly $p$ pairs is given by
\begin{equation*}
        \mathbb{P}_{n}^{(r)}(p)
        = \frac{\binom{n}{p} \binom{n-p}{r-2p} 2^{r-2p}}{\binom{2n}{r}}.
\end{equation*}
For $n = 15$ and $r \in \{6,8,10\}$. The function (assuming the continuous factorial equivalents) looks like this:
[image]

> I am interested in finding the area under that curve, namely
>   $$\int_{0}^{\frac{r}{2}} \frac{\binom{n}{p} \binom{n-p}{r-2p} 2^{r-2p}}{\binom{2n}{r}} \ \text{d}p$$

I consulted this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864930/evaluate-int-x-choose-n-dx-problem-798-crux-mathematicorum) but could derive how that would help me.

I also thought about writing the first product of binomial coefficients as $$
\binom{n}{n - p}\binom{n - p}{r - 2p}
$$
which is similar to the form $\binom{f(x)}{f(y)} \binom{f(y)}{f(x)}$ mentioned in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2602215/int-01-int-01-binom-textsomething-textsomething-binom-textsomethin).

Comment: I would expect the large $n,r$ limit to be unity for any ratio $n/r\geq 1$, since the difference between $\sum_p$ and $\int dp$ should vanish in that limit (and $\sum_p$ is obviously unity).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect some form of CLT for large $n, r$, which may possibly be proved by adopting Laplace's method of approximating the integrand by an appropriate gaussian kernel.

Interestingly enough, we can prove that:

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\binom{n}{p}\binom{n-p}{r-2p}2^{r-2p}}{\binom{2n}{r}}\,\mathrm{d}p = 1. $$

To show this, we may apply the [Legendre duplication formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html) to write

$$ \frac{\binom{n}{p}\binom{n-p}{r-2p}2^{r-2p}}{\binom{2n}{r}} = \frac{n!}{\binom{2n}{r}} \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\Gamma(1+p)\Gamma(n-r+1+p)\Gamma(\frac{r}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-p)\Gamma(\frac{r}{2}+1-p)}$$

and then apply the Ramanujan's beta integral (see the formula (5.3.14) of [DLMF: 5.13](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.13)).

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Carlo's answer, someone noted in response to one of my questions once that for a unimodal nonnegative function $f$, we have 
$$ \biggl| \sum_{i=0}^k f(i) - \int_0^k f(x)\,dx \biggr|
  \le 2\max_{0\le x\le k} f(x).$$
The proof is by drawing a picture.

So to prove closeness of the sum and integral it suffices to prove that the function is unimodal and has a decreasing maximum. That shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: In your case the sum is exactly 1, so if $\max f \to 0$ then the integral converges to 1.

Comment: For odd $r$, too? Because the $\sum_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{r}{2} \right\rfloor} \mathbb{P}_n^{(r)} = 1$, but the upper bound of the integral is $\frac{r}{2}$, not rounded down.

Comment: The extra $1/2$ in the range won't contribute more than $\max f$ to the integral, so it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, I would expect the large $n,r$
 limit to be unity for any ratio $f=r/n\in(0,1]$, since the difference between $\sum_p$ and $\int dp$ should vanish in that limit (and $\sum_p \mathbb{P}_{n}^{(r)}(p)=1$ by normalization). Proving this might be cumbersome, but the numerical evidence is clear:

[image]

Plot of $\int_0^{fn/2} \mathbb{P}_{n}^{(fn)}(p)\,dp$ versus $n$ for $f=1/4,1/2,3/4,1$. The convergence to unity is slower for smaller $f$, but it's there, as expected.

Comment: But can one find a explicit closed form?

Comment: you mean a closed-form expression for this integral for any value of $r,n$? this is unlikely to be forthcoming, but note that for $r/n\gtrsim 1/2$ the integral is already close to unity for $r$ of order 10.

Comment: Yes, I do. Why is that the case and what would be the / a general strategy for approaching such integrals?